# C++03 Replace Preprocessor Directives with Template Metaprogramming

Tags: c++, preprocessor, template-specialization, c++03

I have a embedded C++03 codebase that needs to support different vendors of gadgets, but only ever one at a time. Most of the functions overlap between the several gadgets, but there are a few exclusives, and these exclusive functions are creating a problem that I need to solve.

Here is an example of clumsy code that works using pre-processor conditionals:

```
#define HW_TYPE1    0
#define HW_TYPE2    1

#define HW_TYPE HW_TYPE1

struct  GadgetBase  {
    void    FncA();
    // Many common methods and functions
    void    FncZ();
};
#if HW_TYPE==HW_TYPE2
struct  Gadget  :   public  GadgetBase  {
    bool    Bar()       {return(true);}
};
#else
struct  Gadget  :   public  GadgetBase  {
    bool    Foo()       {return(false);}
};
#endif

Gadget  A;

#if HW_TYPE==HW_TYPE2
bool    Test()  {return(A.Bar());}
#else
bool    Test()  {return(A.Foo());}
```

Here is my attempt at converting the above code to C++ templates without pre-processor directives.
The following code does not compile due to an error in the definition of `Test()` on my particular platform, because either `Foo()` or `Bar()` is undefined depending on the value of `Type`.

```
enum    TypeE   {
    eType1,
    eType2
};

const TypeE Type= eType1; // Set Global Type

// Common functions for both Gadgets
struct  GadgetBase  {
    void    FncA();
    // Many common methods and functions
    void    FncZ();
};

// Unique functions for each gadget
template<TypeE  E=  eType1>
struct  Gadget  :   public  GadgetBase          {
    bool    Foo()       {return(false);}
};
template<>
struct  Gadget<eType2>  :   public  GadgetBase  {
    bool    Bar()       {return(true);}
};

Gadget<Type>    A;
template<TypeE  E=  eType1>
bool    Test()  {return(A.Foo());}
template<>
bool    Test()  {return(A.Bar());}
```

I want to do this with templates to keep the number of code changes down when a new type or additional functions are added.  There are currently five types with at least two more expected soon. The pre-processor implementation code reeks, I want to clean this up before it gets unwieldy.

The gadget code is a small amount of the total code base, so breaking up the entire project per gadget may not be ideal either.

Even though only one type will ever be used for each project, the unused types still have to compile, how do I best design this using C++03 (no constexpr, const if, etc)? Am I completely approaching this wrongly? I am willing to do a complete overhaul.

**EDIT:**
Tomek's solution below makes me wonder if it violates LSP.  Effectively, another way to look at this is having `Test()` be part of an interface that requires implementation.  So, the example can be reconsidered like the following:

```
struct  GadgetI    {
    virtual bool Test()=0;
};
template<TypeE  E=  eType1>
struct  Gadget  :   public  GadgetBase, public GadgetI  {
    bool    Foo()       {return(false);}
    bool    Test()      {return Foo();}
};
template<>
struct  Gadget<eType2>  :   public  GadgetBase, public GadgetI  {
    bool    Bar()       {return(true);}
    bool    Test()      {return Bar();}
};
template<>
struct  Gadget<eType3>  :   public  GadgetBase, public GadgetI  {
    bool    Test()      {} // Violation of LSP?
};
```

Or similarly with the edited example:

```
template<typename T>
bool Test(T& o)              {}  // Violation?
template<>
bool Test(Gadget<eType1> &o) {return(o.Foo());}
template<>
bool Test(Gadget<eType2> &o) {return(o.Bar());}

Test(A);
```

I might be over-thinking this, I just don't want a poor design now to bite me later.

Comment: Hard to tell.... You likely CAN substitute Gadget<whatever> whenever GadgetBase is needed and expect it to behave identically judging from the code you provided. But I cannot be 100% sure as I don't know the purpose of the classes and why you decided to have different methods in different children. Anyway, if GadgetBase is intended as a public parent it should have at least one virtual method and public virtual or protected non-virtual destructor.

Comment: One of the tests for LSP violations is: "Empty, do-nothing implementations of one or more methods in subclasses", that is the source of my agita, but I am getting over it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree the code looks convoluted, I'm with you there. But I believe you are going in the wrong direction. Templates seem cool but they are not the right tool in this case. With templates you WILL always compile all the options every time, even if they are not used.

You want the opposite. You want to ONLY compile one source at a time. The proper way to have the best of both worlds is to separate each implementation in a different file and then pick which file to include/compile using external methods.

Build systems usually have plenty of tools for this respect. For example, for compiling natively, we can rely on CMAKE's own [CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR.html) to identify which is the current processor.

If you want to [cross compile](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/Cross%20Compiling%20With%20CMake.html) you need to specify which platform you want to compile to.

Case in mind, I have a software that needs to be compiled in many operating systems like Redhat, CentOS, Ubuntu, Suse and Windows/Mingw. I have one bash script file that checks for the environment and loads a [toolchain cmake file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE.html) specific for that operating system.

Your case seems to be even simpler. You could just indicate which platform you'd like to use and instruct the build system to compile just the file specific to that platform.

Comment: MadFred, 

Thank you for your response.

I believe that you are suggesting that I create a new implementation file for each of the unique gadget functions and use a different tool-chain command for each build.

Can you help me understand how this is different that the Pre-processor (PP) solution that I have above? But instead of conditional directives, it is just putting the code in different translation units. Effectively we are just hiding the code from the compiler in different ways, right?  How is this preferable to the PP solution?

Comment: @willdo Sure, this is VERY similar to the preprocessor in the sense that only the needed code will be submitted to the compiler. However it is a cleaner solution. You can see this applied in the C library and the Linux kernel where they have folders for each platform. But it is all a matter of scale. If you have just a couple of classes within a couple variations use the preprocessor. But if you want to support a handful or more, the code becomes too bewildering to treat and it is better to split into files.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting there :).

Rewrite your `Test` function so it doesn't rely on global Gadget object but instead takes one as a templated parameter:

```
template<class T>
bool Test(T &o, std::integral_constant<bool (T::*)(), &T::Foo> * = 0)
{
  return(o.Foo());
}

template<class T>
bool Test(T &o, std::integral_constant<bool (T::*)(), &T::Bar> * = 0)
{
  return(o.Bar());
}
```

And call it as:

```
Test(A);
```

This relies on SFINAE (Substitution Failure Is Not An Error) idiom. Based on the definitions compiler will deduce the type of `T` to be a `Gadget`. Now, depending on availability of the `Foo` and `Bar` function it will pick one of the overloads.

Please note this code WILL BREAK if both `Foo` and `Bar` are defined in `Gadget` as the two overloads will match.

This brings a question if you just can't wrap calls to Foo and Bar inside a `Gadget` class:

```
template<TypeE  E=  eType1>
struct  Gadget  :   public  GadgetBase          {
    bool    Foo()       {return(false);}
    bool    Test()      {return Foo();}
};
template<>
struct  Gadget<eType2>  :   public  GadgetBase  {
    bool    Bar()       {return(true);}
    bool    Test()      {return Bar();}
};
```

and consistently call `A.Test()` instead?

EDIT:

I might have over-complicated it. The following overload may be an easier approach to this:

```
bool Test(Gadget<eType1> &o)
{
  return(o.Foo());
}

bool Test(Gadget<eType2> &o)
{
  return(o.Bar());
}

Test(A);
```

Comment: Tomek,  

Thanks for the response.  Two comments. 
1. I believe that [integral_constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) was introduced in C++11.  

2. It seems like your solution is a bit like the Visitor pattern. That is cool.  The issue that I have with the EDITED solution is: what if I have a third gadget that does not have a need for `Test()? If I make an empty Test for the third gadget, wouldn't the code begin to smell?

Comment: Add an empty, catch all, template which does nothing. And integral_constant is trivial to implement even on C++03.

Comment: Thanks.  I edited the OP above to reflect this contribution but I have a question about a possible LSP violation.  If I am running into a limitation of C++03, then that is fine.  It is what it is.